# Granting sudo access to a SELinux confined user in freeIPA

Tags: sudo, selinux, freeipa

I'm using [freeIPA](http://www.freeipa.org) to define RBAC, HBAC and `sudo` rules, as well as SELinux user mappings for a domain of a couple hundred virtual machines, where I need to grant different levels of access to several teams (developers, database administrators, system administrators, management, ...).

Currently, the SELinux policy on these machines is set to `targeted`, and I'm pondering the possibility of deleting the `unconfined_u` SELinux user in order to make these systems run under a `strict` policy.

In order to do that, one of the requirements is to make transparent to the end user the fact that he/she has been 'demoted' from `unconfined_u` to `staff_u`. The problem resides in the way `sudo` interoperates with the SELinux user mappings. Some facts:

1. if you want to use a confined SELinux user and you want to still be able to use `sudo`, you need to use `staff_u`, as this is the SELinux user [with access to SETUID executables](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Targeted_Policy-Confined_and_Unconfined_Users.html).
2. when a user logs into a system, he/she is assigned a SELinux user mapping. That mapping does not change even in the case the SELinux user can run `su` (`unconfined_u`) or `sudo` (`unconfined_u`, `staff_u`).
3. the `SELinux Spec` for `sudo` currently contains facilities to run commands in defined `types` and `roles`, but lacks the possibility of specifying the `user` too. Further reference can be found [here](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man.html).
4. the machines involved in this deployment are all freeIPA clients and their `sudo` policies are managed by freeIPA, but they also have a `puppet` managed, customized `/etc/sudoers` file, provided as a fallback in case of a freeIPA failure.

My first attempt to solve this problem involved witting a policy module containing the needed rules to allow `staff_u` access to the unmodified `sudorules`. This approach has proven to be wrong, because the policy can grow indefinitely and finally what you are doing is punching a hole in the policy.

So the way I have dealt with this these facts so far has been rewriting the `sudorules` to explicitly contain a call to `runcon` to switch to the appropriate SELinux user, so a typical developer now needs to run, for example:

```
$ sudo -u jboss runcon -u sysadm_u jboss_cli.sh
```

This has the drawback of having to modify all the existing `sudorules` and forcing the user to change the way the usually run stuff. So the questions are:

- is there a way to explicitly define the SELinux user in a `Runas_Spec` definition?
- if not possible via `sudoers`, is it possible to define, or otherwise bind, a `sudorule` to a SELinux user mapping in freeIPA?

---

Consider this scenario:

```
# ipa sudorule-show services_4_operators_3
  Rule name: services_4_operators_3
  Description: Operator Level 3 access to service management commands
  Enabled: TRUE
  User Groups: operators_3
  Host Groups: all-hosts
  Sudo Allow Command Groups: services
  Sudo Option: type=sysadm_t, role=sysadm_r

# ipa sudocmdgroup-show services
  Sudo Command Group: services
  Description: commands for services and daemons management
  Member Sudo commands: /sbin/service, /sbin/chkconfig
```

If I try:

```
$ sudo service sshd status
sudo: unable to open /var/log/sudo-io/seq: Permission denied
```

```
time->Wed Sep 11 09:57:30 2013
type=PATH msg=audit(1378886250.584:46644668): item=0 name="/var/log/sudo-io/seq" inode=154 dev=fd:0c mode=0100600 ouid=0 ogid=1168000009 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0
type=CWD msg=audit(1378886250.584:46644668):  cwd="/home/some_user"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1378886250.584:46644668): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7fff2e7ab970 a1=42 a2=180 a3=0 items=1 ppid=2374 pid=2442 auid=1168000009 uid=1168000009 gid=1168000009 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=1168000009 sgid=1168000009 fsgid=1168000009 tty=pts0 ses=6459 comm="sudo" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" subj=staff_u:staff_r:staff_sudo_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key="access"
type=AVC msg=audit(1378886250.584:46644668): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=2442 comm="sudo" name="seq" dev=dm-12 ino=154 scontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_sudo_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Because I'm using `log_output` in `Defaults` and:

```
# ll -dZ /var/log/sudo-io
drwx------. root root system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   /var/log/sudo-io/
```

Trying to "fix" this AVC denial will result in the aforementioned infinite policy module, because allowing:

```
allow staff_sudo_t var_log_t:file { open read write lock create };
allow staff_sudo_t var_log_t:dir { write add_name create search };
```

is a spurious problem, as shown when enabling such permissions:

```
$ sudo service sshd status
env: /etc/init.d/sshd: Permission denied
```

```
time->Wed Sep 11 11:00:53 2013
type=PATH msg=audit(1378890053.185:46646934): item=0 name="/etc/init.d/sshd" inode=5490 dev=fd:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:sshd_initrc_exec_t:s0
type=CWD msg=audit(1378890053.185:46646934):  cwd="/"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1378890053.185:46646934): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=no exit=-13 a0=7fffc0829862 a1=7fffc0829578 a2=607030 a3=ffffe000 items=1 ppid=6715 pid=6720 auid=1168000009 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts2 ses=6459 comm="env" exe="/bin/env" subj=staff_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1378890053.185:46646934): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=6720 comm="env" name="sshd" dev=dm-1 ino=5490 scontext=staff_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:sshd_initrc_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
```

---

## FINAL EDIT

I have finally adopted a mid-term solution. I have configured my IPA server as follows:

```
$ sudo -u dsastrem ipa config-show
  Maximum username length: 32
  Home directory base: /home
  Default shell: /bin/rbash
  Default users group: ipausers
  Default e-mail domain: company.com
  Search time limit: 2
  Search size limit: 100
  User search fields: uid,givenname,sn,telephonenumber,ou,title
  Group search fields: cn,description
  Enable migration mode: FALSE
  Certificate Subject base: O=COMPANY.COM
  Password Expiration Notification (days): 4
  Password plugin features: AllowNThash
  SELinux user map order: guest_u:s0$xguest_u:s0$user_u:s0$staff_u:s0-s0:c0.c1023$unconfined_u:s0-s0:c0.c1023
  Default SELinux user: guest_u:s0
  Default PAC types: MS-PAC
```

and I have defined some SELinux user mappings similar to this one that bind some RBACs to a SELinux user (`staff_u`).

```
$ sudo -u dsastrem ipa selinuxusermap-find
---------------------------
X SELinux User Maps matched
---------------------------
  ....

  Rule name: semap_operators_3_mad
  SELinux User: staff_u:s0-s0:c0.c1023
  HBAC Rule: operators_3_access
  Description: SELinux user mapping for MAD level 3 operators
  Enabled: TRUE

  ....
----------------------------
Number of entries returned X
----------------------------
```

My `sudo` rules now look like this one:

```
  Rule name: services_4_operators_3
  Description: Operator Level 3 access to service management commands
  Enabled: TRUE
  User Groups: operators_3
  Host Groups: all-hosts
  Sudo Allow Command Groups: services
  Sudo Option: role=unconfined_r
```

This is not my final goal, as I wanted to completely eliminate `unconfined_u`, but it's a good step forward, as it enhances a little bit the overall security. Of course, Matthew's answer is correct, as `staff_u` should be able to transition to a higher privileged domain via `sudo` options; but there's still the problem of `system_u` not being completely equipped to replace `unconfined_u`. Maybe because it is not intended to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are aware that you can move into the `sysadm_r` role as `staff_u` right?

For example, the following below would work.

```
myuser  ALL=(ALL)   TYPE=sysadm_t ROLE=sysadm_r PASSWD: ALL
```

This will allow you to do (almost) what you can do as root as unconfined.

Oh and one final tip. Using `su` is a bit tricky with RBAC (it does a lot of stuff which gets it into all sorts of places). Instead you can use the `runuser` command which does the same thing without a lot of `su` overheads.

I actually restrict `su` use in sudoers like so;

```
%wheel   ALL=(ALL)   TYPE=sysadm_t ROLE=sysadm_r NOPASSWD: ALL, ! /bin/su
```

Because by default the SELinux policy doesn't allow the `sudo` transition to manage the necessary signals. Really people should probably just use `sudo -i` anyway.

I normally hardlink `runuser` to `ru` as a two-letter replacement for people who prefer to run `sudo su -` out of a bad habit (like me!).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that (see #3). No (freeIPA) user is ever going to run `su`, I mentioned it for the sake of completeness. Both `runuser` and/or `sudo -i` are out of the equation here too, as none of them changes the user mapping of the target command and I'm not allowing anybody actually `login` as another user.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Why is is necessary to switch selinux users when you can set them to a user that can switch between roles?