# SE Linux - can't change SELinux booleans with sudo

Tags: centos6, sudo, selinux

I think this is the correct place to put this, rather than in StackOverflow

Either way, we have a CentOS 6.6 server.  SElinux isn't allowing us to enable httpd_can_sendmail

I've tried this....

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

I then get this

```
/usr/sbin/getsebool httpd_can_sendmail
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
```

I tried with this too

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail true
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

Comment: Just a random thought: does the command work correctly from an interactive root session? i.e. `sudo -i` and then `setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on`

Comment: Yes!  That seems to work.  Do you want to answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sudo` command and managing SELinux requires some additional handling, but typically simply running the command from an interactive root session is easiest:

```
$ sudo -i 
  Password: 
# setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

I think the issue is that you need to specify a role as part of the sudo command:

> **`-r role`**     The `-r` (role) option causes the new (SELinux) security context to have the role specified by role.

From what I understand that should be setting up `/etc/sudoers` correctly and then:

```
sudo -r sysadm_r -u root setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

should do the trick, but I can't really test now.

This question appears related: [Granting sudo access to a SELinux confined user in freeIPA](https://serverfault.com/questions/537912/granting-sudo-access-to-a-selinux-confined-user-in-freeipa)

Comment: The first suggestion (sudo -i before the command) seems to have worked